# Auto Download of photos working in WhatsApp Desktop App, but not in mobile App

Tags: facebook, mobile, whatsapp

A couple of months back, I was working on a project and all the collaborators were staying in touch via WhatsApp. As it is a fairly large group of about 80 people, lots of photos tend to get generated each day. Since I was working on my laptop, I decided to use the desktop application rather than the mobile app, as it was more convenient. We were required to complete a certain task, within a fairly short amount of time, so everybody was working full throttle at that moment. As the deadline was approaching, the number of photos in the WhatsApp group started to increase. Moreover, as the navigation in the desktop application was becoming difficult, I decided to switch to the android app.

To my surprise, absolutely none of the photos had been downloaded on the app. As per my knowledge, whatever auto-download settings are applied to the mobile app, are also followed by the desktop application. But that didn't happen.

I've checked all my settings and everything seems to be fine. All permissions have been granted. There is no data usage check applied. But still, the auto-download feature didn't work on my phone, while it did flawlessly on the desktop application.

After that incident, there have been several other instances wherein auto-download was only working on the desktop application, instead of working on both the desktop and mobile version of WhatsApp in tandem. This has begun to worry me a little, as it is affecting my work. Can anyone suggest any tips to fix this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not enabled.
Go to settings and see if it's enabled.  If it ain't,  enable it (but it is by default).
If it still doesn't work, delete WhatsApp and download it again.
This happened to me and I solved it by the same way.
Best to you!